# How to pass argument from Java using HashMap to myBatis?

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

How to pass input parameter as array in myBatis stored Procedure using Java?

In my case I pass Long [] array

I want to pass value as array in my stored procedure input, and I am trying to put jdbcType=ARRAY but I got error,

```
ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot convert java.sql.Array
```

Can you help in code

An error in my code...?

For your reference I added my code. This is my spring DAO layer for user. From here i need to call myBatis

UserDAO.java

```
@Autowired
public void setSqlSessionTemplate(SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate) {
    super.setSqlSessionTemplate(SqlSessionTemplate)
}


public List<User> getUserList(List<Long> userId) {
    Long[] arr = userId.toArray(new Long[userId.size()]);
    Map<String,Object> queryParameter = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    queryParameter.put("P_PARAM_ID_ARR",arr);// Here i got error how to convert Long[] to  java.sql.Array.
    this.sqlSession().selectList("getUserDatas",queryParameter);
    List<User> userList = (List<User>)queryParameter.get("P_RST");

}
```

This is my myBatis Queries xml file
userqueries.xml

```
<mapper namespace = "userDAO">
    <resultMap id= "userMapping" type="com.User">
        <result property="id" column="USER_ID" javaType="java.lang.Long"></result>
        <result property="name" column="USER_NAME" javaType="java.lang.String"></result>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getUserDatas" parameterType="java.util.Map" statementType="CALLABLE" resultMap="userMapping">

    { call PROC_USER(#{P_PARAM_ID_ARR, jdbcType=ARRAY, mode=IN}, #{P_RST, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet, jdbcType=CURSOR, mode=OUT, resultMap="userMapping"})}

    </select>

</mapper>
```

When I am trying to rum I always get 500 error.

How to pass array as argument in procedure?

Thankyou Please help me.....

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in JDBC need to be created through the factory method on java.sql.Connection.  Something like this:

```
Long[] arr = userId.toArray(new Long[userId.size()]);
Array sqlArray = sqlSession().getConnection().createArrayOf("int", arr);
Map<String,Object> queryParameter = new HashMap<String,Object>();
queryParameter.put("P_PARAM_ID_ARR",sqlArray);
```